# Export APA format table of lme4 anova results

Tags: r, datatable, lme4, anova, mlm

I ran this MLM model

```
model1.a <- lmer(log10_number_of_sensations ~  Tone*Location + Tone*Intensity 
           +(1+Tone+Intensity|Subject), 
           neutralBlock_data,REML=TRUE)
```

and I used "lmertest" to get the repeated measure anova table:

```
a1.a = anova(model1.a, ddf="Kenward-Roger")
```

How can I save the RM ANOVA table in APA style?

I tried to use the following packages:

flextable(stats.table <- as.data.frame(report(a1.a)))
[image]
But I wander I can I present the P value

as it was here:
[image]

thank you very much

Comment: (1) Can we have a [mcve] please? (2) you can check the options at https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MixedModels.html#model-presentation-and-prediction

Answer (score 1):

Install the `apaTables` package.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/apaTables/apaTables.pdf

Maybe try:

```
mytab <- apa.aov.table(model1.a) 
print(mytab)
```

There are a variety of table options in that package for different models.

Comment: I afraid that this package is not easy to use for lme4 model

Answer (score 0):

Here are some other options for multilevel models
https://www.anthonyschmidt.co/post/2020-09-06-table-options-mlm/